# Generated screenshot for login page is blank

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying blow code for creating screenshot using phantomJS 2.1.1 but getting blank screenshot. Can please tell me what i did wrong?

```
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open('https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/#/signIn',function({
        setTimeout(function() {
        page.render('sigview.png');
        phantom.exit();
        }, 1000);
    });
```

I expected it will capture whole page of screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

When I add:

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};
```

Then I get:

```
CONSOLE: Google Analytics Initialized (from line # in "")
CONSOLE: jQuery.Deferred exception: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Object.assign({},d,o)') t@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:8081643
o@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/scripts.e53141f8.js:1:8772726
invoke@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:464073
https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:458160
invoke@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:464073
https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:462631
getService@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:460540
injectionArgs@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:463648
instantiate@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:464197
https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:518515
createDetachedTour@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/scripts.e53141f8.js:1:11736460
https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/scripts.e53141f8.js:1:3025948
invoke@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:464073
https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:462993
forEach@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:427302
createInjector@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:462942
doBootstrap@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:438797
bootstrap@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:439323
angularInit@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:438068
https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:722817
mightThrow@https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:237532
https://sigview.sigmoid.io/app/scripts/vendor.00e53c4a.js:1:238173 undefined (from line # in "")
```

I suspect the `undefined` errors make PhantomJs choke.

My lazy fix would be, not to use a deprecated library like PhantomJS and try https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer :)

Comment: I agree with the assessment. You can improve your post by summarily describing how PhantomJS works (that is: it's a specific Chrome version) and how to do it with node+puppeteer (or chrome headless). If you don't have a working example, one can be extracted from this little project of mine: [https://github.com/filippopossenti/openly-pdfgen](https://github.com/filippopossenti/openly-pdfgen) :D